# If I install anaconda, do I still have to use vscode?

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, dataset

I'm new in programming, actually I use it for Machine Learning.
I have installed python and anaconda (I don't know if that is right, or I have to install only anaconda?).
And I can see in start menu: (Anaconda powershell, Jupyter, Spyder, Anaconda navigator, Anaconda prompt).
So my question is: Do I still have to use vscode as IDE, or one of the listed programs that come with anaconda? If the answer is the second choice, I will ask, which one of them?

Thanks.

I'm using python just because I have a project in ML, So I must to set the necessary things for ML, like libraries, dataset, and algorithms. Then I have to learn how to use them.
Any help will be very apprecheated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anaconda is a Python distribution, that not only comes with Python itself, but a lot of additional Python packages from the "scientific stack", like numpy, pandas, matplotlib, scipy, scikit-learn: exactly what you need for ML. You don't have to install anything else from python.org.

Anaconda also comes with the Spyder IDE. This is the perfect choice for a Python beginner. **You don't need VSCode**. VSCode is way more flexible than Spyder, but you have to get used to it.

**Conda** is the package manager that comes with Anaconda. Do yourself a favour an learn some conda basics and how to use virtual environments here: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html

The important difference between Anaconda and pure Python is that you have to **activate a conda environment** - even the "base" environemnt - before you can use it. This is not obvious to a beginner.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful information and advice.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use vcscode. Anaconda is only a python with extra features, but to code you would appreciate the VSCOde. It comes with many features and you can install extensions to burst your experience. Go for it.